# Div is not covering the content in it (vertically) no floats inside of div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My div is not covering all of the content in it. I researched this, and all I can find is this problem is due to floats and to fix it you add this to the css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Yet in my div there are no floats, and the answer above is not solving the problem. What the code above is doing is it hides the extra content that is not covered by the div (div is only used for background color of the content).

This is the code for my div:

```
#div {
  width: 570px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  //overflow: hidden; doesn't fix anything.
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Can you also post the HTML with an example of the problem? Maybe in a [Pen](http://codepen.io)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroReneses It is around 300 lines of html in between that div. If it is necessary I will post. I am going through my html right now to make sure that all the tags are good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a case of a collapsing DIV; there are several methods that will work.

Different designs take different methods to fix them.

The **overflow method** you mentioned is one.

- You can also create another div inside that had `clear: both;` which will put the empty div after the floats, therefore giving the wrapper div size.
- There is also a **clearfix** method that uses the `:after`

For more details, see this article: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

**UPDATE**

With no floats, the other issue I have seen is that there is no height information; sometimes, you also need to provide a height to the parent object.

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE**

Based on our conversations on this issue, I am posting this ...

Also remember to watch the height and position of the child elements.  Incorrect settings can do some strange things.

Comment: there are no floats. I used 0 floats. I even ctr+f float but none come up in either files.

Comment: Added an update ... try setting a height on the element; you may need to do this to a parent object, as well ... it gets to be a bit of a balancing act sometimes.

Comment: `position: relative` on the child elements can sometimes work.

Comment: it was a height issue...THANKS! fixed a height in the css and now it is fine!

Comment: I had to change a height on one of the divs inside the main div...-.-, but thanks for the update it made me look at the heights of content inside the main div.

Comment: Usually, it's getting our thoughts running in a different direction that helps; glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `z-index: 0` for the div css